# Measure objects length and width by picture (pixels)

Tags: image-processing

I am quite new to image processing. I have experimented with opencv and tried to measure the lenght and width of an object from a picture using a reference object where I know the dimensions.

See this Link https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/

Thats working quite well, as long as the objects have the same depth.
[image: Two quarters but the right one is way closer to the camera]

Is there a way to determine the distance of the object by algorithms when the camera is fixed? I was thinking about ultrasonic sensors, but I would need quite alot of them to make this work. Any other ideas? I appreciate any help :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_imaging, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_RealSense